# How to set a UIImageView as a phone's wallpaper

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, wallpaper

When you have a UIImageView which has been sent the following messages:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SteveJobsMacbookAir.JPG"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 20.0, 160.0, 230.0)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
```

How can you then set this image as the phone's wallpaper?

Comment: You can't. 3rd party iOS apps can't directly set a device's wallpaper.

Comment: Oh :( I had a feeling that was the case, though all the resources suggesting this were from 2011 & prior. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no public API in iOS that allows you to modify the phone's wallpaper.

The best solution is to save your photo to the user's photo album, and prompt them to set it themselves from the device's Settings app.